# modal is not redirecting to the expected file

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

when button is clicked its not firing the page ,actually this is working in localhost ,after hosting to live server its not working.

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="showAjaxModal('<?php echo 
site_url('modal/popup/application_add'); ?>');" 
<class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
<i class="entypo-plus-circled"></i>
<?php echo get_phrase('add_new_application'); ?>
</a>
```

Comment: Please check your siteurl

Comment: Kindly provide necessary code so we can provide you with better answer. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please check it